# Which Premchand stories are written in Hindi and which in Urdu?

Tags: translation, urdu-language, hindi-language, premchand

The Indian writer [Premchand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premchand) started off writing in Urdu, and started writing Hindi stories later in his career. According to Wikipedia:

> In 1914, Munshi Premchand started writing in Hindi (Hindi and Urdu are considered different registers of a single language Hindustani, with Hindi drawing much of its vocabulary from Sanskrit and Urdu being more influenced by Persian). By this time, he was already reputed as a fiction writer in Urdu. Sumit Sarkar notes that the switch was prompted by the difficulty of finding publishers in Urdu.

As someone who speaks neither Hindi nor Urdu (but can at least see the difference in written text, since they use different alphabets), how can I tell whether a given Premchand story, which I'm reading in English translation, was originally written in Urdu or in Hindi?

For example, the short story ["Catastrophe"](https://www.thefreshreads.com/catastrophe-vidhwans/), which has already had a few questions asked about it on this site - was it originally in Urdu or in Hindi? The collection [*Short Stories of Premchand*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.20749/page/n5/mode/2up), available on the Internet Archive, has a Translator's Note which discusses in general the translation of Premchand's work from both Hindi and Urdu to English - are the stories in this volume translated from Urdu, from Hindi, or a mixture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Detailed publication information regarding Premchand's short stories—along with valuable comments on the differences between the Urdu and Hindi versions—is available in the "Notes" at the end of each of the four volumes of *Premchand: the complete short stories* (2017), edited by M. Asaduddin and published by Penguin Books. From the foreword by Harish Trivedi:

> It is now possible to say with certainty which of the two versions of the story was first published, and in the great majority of the cases it is clear that the version first published was also the first to be written.

He goes on to say:

> Though the early translations from Urdu into Hindi were mostly done by Premchand himself, we have firm evidence, for example, that the final manuscript of the Hindi *Rangbhumi* was translated into Urdu by another person who demanded a rate that Premchand thought to be exorbitant. In any case, all his works throughout his life in both Hindi and Urdu were published under Premchand's own name with no mention of a translator and are treated by the common reader as being equally original.

A sample entry from the "Notes" section, when there are no additional comments regarding differences between the Urdu and Hindi versions, is as follows (taken for the short story *This Is My Homeland*, translated into English from Urdu for volume 1 by M. Asaduddin):

> First published in Urdu with the title 'Yehi Mera Watan Hai' in the Urdu anthology, *Soz-e Watan* (1908). Now available in *Kulliyaat-e Premchand* 9 (2000). It was published in Hindi with the title 'Yehi Meri Matribhumi Hai' in *Prem Prasun* (1924).

The bare bones of this information has been compiled into the table below for all the stories in this collection. The entry for the year is bolded if it is for the version published first.

| S.No. | Title in English | Title in Urdu | Year | Title in Hindi | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Love for the World and Patriotism | Ishq Duniya aur Hubb-e Watan | **1908** | Sansarik Prem aur Desh Prem | 1961 |
| 2. | The Rarest Pearl in the World | Duniya ka Sab Se Anmol Ratan | **1908** | Duniya ka Sab Se Anmol Ratan | 1961 |
| 3. | Sheikh Makhmoor | Sheikh Makhmoor | **1908** | Sheikh Makhmoor | 1961 |
| 4. | Sorrow's Reward | Sila-e Maatam | **1908** | Shok ka Puraskar | 1961 |
| 5. | This Is My Homeland | Yehi Mera Watan Hai | **1908** | Yehi Meri Matribhumi Hai | 1924 |
| 6. | Dara Shikoh's Durbar | Dara Shikoh ka Darbar | **1908** | *Transliterated* | 1988 |
| 7. | The Pyre of Sin | Atishkada-e Gunaah Gunaah ka Agankund | **1910** 1930 | Paap ka Agnikund | 1917 |
| 8. | The Travels of a Dervish | Sair-e Dervish | **1910** | Shaap | 1924 |
| 9. | A Hunt | Shikaar | **1910** | Shikaar | 1931 |
| 10. | Rani Sarandha | Rani Sarandha | **1910** | Rani Sarandha | 1917 |
| 11. | Selfless Benefactor | Be-gharaz Mohsin | **1910** | Neki | 1962 |
| 12. | A Well-bred Daughter | Badey Ghar ki Beti | **1910** | Badey Ghar ki Beti | 1910 |
| 13. | The Sword of Vikramaditya | Vikramaditya ka Tegha | **1911** | Vikramaditya ka Tegha | 1962 |
| 14. | A Strange Revenge | Karishma-e Intiqaam | **1911** | Advut Pratishod | 1979 |
| 15. | From Both Sides | Dono Taraf Se | **1911** | Dono Taraf Se | 1976 |
| 16. | Raja Hardaul | Raja Hardaul | **1911** | Raja Hardaul | 1917 |
| 17. | The Elder Sister | Badi Behn | **1911** | Badi Behn | 1980 |
| 18. | The Fear of Dishonour | Khauf-e Ruswaai | **1911** | Khauf-e Ruswaai | 1988 |
| 19. | The Desired Destination | Manzil-e-Maqsood | **1911** | Akhiri Manzil | 1962 |
| 20. | A Poor Woman's Cry | Aah-e Be-kas | **1911** | Ghareeb ki Haai | 1918 |
| 21. | Alha | Alha | **1912** | Alha | 1962 |
| 22. | Mother's Love | Mamta | **1912** | Mamta | 1917 |
| 23. | An Example Is Better than Precepts | Alim Be-amal | **1912** | Nasihoton ka Daftar | 1962 |
| 24. | Making Up | Manawan | **1912** | Manawan | 1962 |
| 25. | Nemesis | Kaifar-e Kirdaar | **1912** | Kaifar-e Kirdaar | 1988 |
| 26. | Royal Arrogance | Raj Hutt | **1912** | Raj Hutt | 1962 |
| 27. | Appearances Are Deceptive | Dhokey ki Tatti | **1912** | Dhokey ki Tatti | 1988 |
| 28. | A Woman's Character | Tirya Charittar | **1913** | Triya Charitra | 1962 |
| 29. | Life and Death | Maut Aur Zindagi Amrit | **1913** 1918 | Amrit | 1962 |
| 30. | The Night of the New Moon | Amaavas ki Raat | **1913** | Amavasya ki Ratri | 1917 |
| 31. | A Glance of Love | Nigaah-e Naz | **1913** | Dharm Sankat | 1918 |
| 32. | Union | Milap | **1913** | Milap | 1962 |
| 33. | A New Dawn | Baang-e Sehar | **1913** | Shankhnaad | 1915 |
| 34. | Injustice | Andher | **1913** | Andher | 1962 |
| 35. | A Bitter Pill | Daru-e Talkh | **1913** | *Transliterated* | 1988 |
| 36. | Only One Voice | Sirf Ek Awaaz | **1913** | Sirf Ek Awaaz | 1962 |
| 37. | The Dandy Landowner | Baanka Zamindar | **1913** | Baanka Zamindar | 1962 |
| 38. | The Salt Inspector | Namak ka Darogha | **1913** | Namak ka Darogha | 1917 |
| 39. | The Orphaned Girl | Anath Ladki | **1914** | Anath Ladki | 1962 |
| 40. | When Blood Turns White | Khoon Safed | **1914** | Khoon Safed | 1918 |
| 41. | The Hunter Prince | Shikari aur Rajkumar | **1914** | Shikari Rajkumar | 1918 |
| 42. | The Funny Tale of a Jailbreak | Sauda-e Khaam | **1918** |  |  |
| 43. | Retribution | Shamat-e Aamal Khak-e Parwana | **1914** 1928 | Apni Karni | 1962 |
| 44. | Remorse | Pachhtawa | **1914** | Pachhtawa | 1917 |
| 45. | An Appropriate Choice | Husn-e-Intekhab | **1914** | Pareeksha | 1917 |
| 46. | The Balm | Marham | **1915** | Vismriti | 1918 |
| 47. | The Sword of Honour | Ghairat ki Katar | **1915** | Ghairat ki Katar | 1962 |
| 48. | The Consequences of Karma | Karmon ka Phal | **1915** | Karmon ka Phal | 1962 |
| 49. | A Daughter's Possessions | Beti ka Dhan | **1915** | Beti ka Dhan | 1918 |
| 50. | Godavari's Suicide | Saut | 1920 | Saut | **1915** |
| 51. | Two Brothers | Do Bhai | **1916** | Do Bhai | 1918 |
| 52. | A Punishment for Honesty | Neki ki Saza (*transliterated*) | 2001 | Sajjanata ka Dand | **1916** |
| 53. | Holy Judges | Panchayat | **1916** | Panch Parmeshwar | 1916 |
| 54. | An Embodiment of Pride | Sar-e Purghuroor | **1916** | Ghamand ka Putla | 1962 |
| 55. | The Lustre of the Firefly | Jugnu ki Chamak | **1916** | Jugnu ki Chamak | 1917 |
| 56. | Deception | Dhoka | **1916** | Dhoka | 1917 |
| 57. | The Door: A Fragment | Darwaza | **1917** | ? | 1988 |
| 58. | The Code of Honour | Rajput ki Beti | **1917** | Maryada ki Vedi | 1917 |
| 59. | The Volcano | Shu'la-e Husn | **1917** | Jwalamukhi | 1918 |
| 60. | Counsel | Masha'le Hidayat | **1917** | Updesh | 1917 |
| 61. | Divine Justice | Imaan ka Faisla | 1917 | Ishwariya Nyay | **1917** |
| 62. | Separation and Union | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Viyog aur Milap | **1917** |
| 63. | The Greater Pilgrimage | Hajj-e Akbar | **1917** | Maha Teerth | 1918 |
| 64. | The Durga Temple | Durga ka Mandir | **1917** | Durga ka Mandir | 1917 |
| 65. | The Captain | Dawa aur Daroo | **1917** | Kaptan Sahib | 1926 |
| 66. | Victory | Fateh | **1918** | Vijay | 1962 |
| 67. | The Sacrifice | Qurbani | 1920 | Balidan | **1918** |
| 68. | The Return | Bazyaft | **1918** | Shanti | 1936 |
| 69. | The Path of Devotion | Raah-e-Khidmat | **1918** | Seva Marg | 1918 |
| 70. | The Chains of Passion | Zanjeer-e Hawas | **1918** | Vasna ki Kadiyan | 1962 |
| 71. | The Dagger of Loyalty | Khanjar-e Wafa | **1918** | Wafa ka Khanjar | 1962 |
| 72. | The Gift of Truth | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Sachai ka Uphar | **1918** |
| 73. | Wisdom | Ibrat | 1928 | Bodh | **1918** |
| 74. | Entanglements | Janjaal | **1918** |  |  |
| 75. | The Bankruptcy of the Bank | Bank ka Diwala | **1919** | Bank ka Diwala | 1926 |
| 76. | Stepmother | Sauteli Ma | **1919** | Vimata | 1921 |
| 77. | Premonition | Khwab-e-Pareshan | **1919** | Anisht Shanka | 1921 |
| 78. | The Murder of Honour | Khoon-e Hurmat | **1919** | Izzat ka Khoon | 1962 |
| 79. | The Bookbinder | Daftari | **1919** | Daftari | 1921 |
| 80. | Atmaram | Atmaram | **1920** | Atmaram | 1921 |
| 81. | The Correction | Islaah | 1920 | Pashu se Manushya | **1920** |
| 82. | The Prime Dharma of Man | Insaan ka Muqaddas Farz | 1920 | Manushya ka Param Dharma | **1920** |
| 83. | Black Face | Roo-e Siyah | 1920 | Pratigya | **1920** |
| 84. | Banter | Nok-Jhonk | 1920 | Brahm ka Swang | **1920** |
| 85. | The Old Aunt | Budhi Kaaki | 1920 | Budhi Kaaki | **1920** |
| 86. | A Father's Love | Mehr-e-Pidar | 1920 | Putra Prem | **1920** |
| 87. | After Death | Ba'd az Marg | **1920** | Mrityu ke Peechey | 1924 |
| 88. | The Blessed Illness | Marz-i Mubarak | **1920** | Mubarak Bimari | 1962 |
| 89. | Life Force | Rooh-e Hayat | **1921** | Rooh-e Hayat/Jeevan ki Pran Shakti | 1988 |
| 90. | The Problem | Muamma | 1921 | Bhisham Samasya | **1921** |
| 91. | A Special Holi | Ajeeb Holi | 1928 | Vichitra Holi | **1921** |
| 92. | The Hidden Hand | Dast-e Ghaib | **1921** | Prarabdha | 1921 |
| 93. | An Audacious Act | Bazm-e Parishaan | **1922**<sup>[1]</sup> | Dussahas | 1921 |
| 94. | The Red Ribbon | Laal Feeta | **1921**<sup>[2]</sup> | Laal Feeta ya Magistrate ka Isteefa | 1921 |
| 95. | When Rivals Became Friends | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Laag-Dant | **1921** |
| 96. | A Positive Change | Tahreek-e Khair | 1922 | Vidhwans | **1921** |
| 97. | A Battle of Ideals | Taalif-e Qalb (original no longer available) *Transliterated* | 1922 2001 | Adarsh Virodh | **1921** |
| 98. | A Philosopher's Love | Philsafi ki Muhabbat | 1921 | Tyagi ka Prem | **1921** |
| 99. | The Bridal Sari | *Transliterated from Hindi to Urdu* | 2001 | Suhaag ki Sari | **1922** |
| 100. | Witchcraft | Mooth | 1922 | Mooth | **1922** |
| 101. | Victory of the Defeated | Shikast ki Fateh | 1922 | Haar ki Jeet | **1922** |
| 102. | Defending One's Liberty | ? | 1924 | Swatva Raksha | **1922** |
| 103. | Cobra Worship | Saanp ki Ma'shooqa *Transliterated* | **1922** 2001 | Naag Puja | 1923 |
| 104. | Turf War | Fikr-e Duniya | 1928 | Adhikar Chinta | **1922** |
| 105. | Hidden Wealth | Dafeena *Transliterated* | 1939 2001 | Gupt Dhan | **1922** |
| 106. | A Dhobi's Honour | Husn-e Zan | **1922** | Lokmat ka Samman | 1947 |
| 107. | Hoodwinked | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Chakma | **1922** |
| 108. | Reincarnation | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Purva Samskara | **1922** |
| 109. | Test | Imtihaan | **1923** | Pariksha | 1938 |
| 110. | A Loyal Subject | Rajya Bhagat (*transliterated*) | 2003 | Rajya Bhakta | **1923** |
| 111. | End of Enmity | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Vair ka Ant | **1923** |
| 112. | The Fool | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Baudam | **1923** |
| 113. | Compulsion | Majboori | **1923** | Nerashya Leela | 1938 |
| 114. | A Home for an Orphan | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Grihdaah | **1923** |
| 115. | Purification | Shuddhi | **1923** | *Transliterated* | 1981 |
| 116. | Autobiography | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Aap Beeti | **1923** |
| 117. | The Ornaments | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Abhushan | **1923** |
| 118. | Revenge | Intiqaam | **1923** | Pratishod | 1962 |
| 119. | Trickery | Chakma | 1930 | Kaushal | **1923** |
| 120. | Satyagraha | ? | 1928 | Satyagrah | **1923** |
| 121. | The Roaming Monkey | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Sailani Bandar | **1924** |
| 122. | The Prophet's Justice | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Nabi ka Niti Nirvaah Nyay | **1924** 1936 |
| 123. | Sudden Downfall | ? | 1929 | Vajrapat | **1924** |
| 124. | Road to Salvation | Raah-e Najaat | 1929 | Mukti Marg | **1924** |
| 125. | Money for Deliverance | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Muktidhan | **1924** |
| 126. | Forgiveness | Wa'fu | **1924** | Kshama | 1938 |
| 127. | The Lashes of Good Fortune | Nekbhakhti ke Tazianey | 1929 | Saubhagya ke Kodey | **1924** |
| 128. | Banishment | Abhagin | 1930 | Niraswan | **1924** |
| 129. | Despair | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Nerashya | **1924** |
| 130. | Ghost | Bhoot | 1929 | Bhoot | **1924** |
| 131. | By a Whisker! | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Ik Aanch ki Kasar | **1924** |
| 132. | Initiation | ? | 1929 | Deeksha | **1924** |
| 133. | Rescue | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Uddhar | **1924** |
| 134. | The Game of Chess | Shatranj ki Baazi | 1924 | Shatranj ke Khiladi | **1924** |
| 135. | One and a Quarter *Ser* of Wheat | Sawa Ser Gehun | **1924** | Sawa Ser Gehun | 1939 |
| 136. | Pleasures of College Life | Maya-e Tafrih | 1925 | Vinod | **1924** |
| 137. | The Malevolent Baby | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Tentar | **1924** |
| 138. | Money for the Decree | ? | 1929 | Decree ke Rupaye | **1925** |
| 139. | The Condemned | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Dhikkar | **1925** |
| 140. | The Path to Hell | Hasrat | 1930 | Nark ka Marg | **1925** |
| 141. | The Secret of Culture | ? | 1929 | Sabyata ka Rahasya | **1925** |
| 142. | Temple and Mosque | ? (original no longer available) *Transliterated* | 1925 2001 | Mandir aur Masjid | **1925** |
| 143. | Faith | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Vishwas | **1925** |
| 144. | Man and Woman | Devi | 1930 | Stree aur Purush | **1925** |
| 145. | A Hired Pony | ? | 1929 | Bhaadey ka Tattu | **1925** |
| 146. | A Mother's Heart | *Transliterated* | 2001 | Maata ka Hriday | **1925** |
| 147. | Theft | Chori | 1930 | Chori | **1925** |
| 148. | The Goddess from Heaven | Jannat ki Devi | 1930 | Swarg ki Devi | **1925** |
| 149. | Punishment | Saza | 1930 | Dand | **1925** |
| 150. | The Outcaste | Neech Zaat ki Ladki | **1925** | Shudra | 1926 |
| 151. | Laila | Laila | 1929 | Laila | **1926** |
| 152. | A Mentor's Advice | Muridi | 1929 | Guru Mantar | **1926** |
| 153. | The Mantra | Taalif | 1928 | Mantra | **1926** |
| 154. | The Thread of Love | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Prem Sutra | **1926** |
| 155. | The Basis of Life | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Aadhar | **1926** |
| 156. | Qazzaqi | Qazzaqi | 1930 | Qazzaqi | **1926** |
| 157. | Disgrace | Fareb | 1936 | Laanchan | **1926** |
| 158. | The Tonga Driver's Reflections | Tangewaley ki Barh | **1926** | Tangewaley ki Barh | 1962 |
| 159. | Ramleela | Ramleela | 1930 | Ramleela | **1926** |
| 160. | An Invitation | Dawat | 1929 | Nimantran | **1926** |
| 161. | Violence Is the Supreme Religion | Deendari | 1930 | Himsa Param Dharma | **1926** |
| 162. | The Excommunicated | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Bahishkaar | **1926** |
| 163. | The Head Clerk | Badey Babu | **1927** | ? | 1962 |
| 164. | Why Do People Marry? | Shadi ki Wajh | **1927** | Shadi ki Wajh | 1962 |
| 165. | Sati | ? | 1934 | Sati | **1927** |
| 166. | The Symphony of the Soul | Naghma-e Rooh | **1927** | Atma Sangeet | 1927 |
| 167. | The Tree of Love | Nakhl-e Ummeed | 1928 | Kamna Taru | **1927** |
| 168. | Soujan, the Devotee | ? | 1933 | Soujan Bhagat | **1927** |
| 169. | Temple | Mandir | 1930 | Mandir | **1927** |
| 170. | The Borrowed Watch | ? | 1929 | Maangey ki Ghadi | **1927** |
| 171. | Babaji's Feast | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Babaji ka Bhog | **1927** |
| 172. | The Actress | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Aiktress | **1927** |
| 173. | Trial by Fire | Mazaar-e Atasheen | 1929 | Agni-Samadhi | **1928** |
| 174. | Moteramji Shastri | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Moteramji Shastri | **1928** |
| 175. | The Spell | Mantar | **1928** | Mantra | 1928 |
| 176. | The Disappointment of Moteramji Shastri | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Moteramji Shastri ka Nerashya | **1928** |
| 177. | Foolish Friend | Naadaan Dost | **1928** | Naadaan Dost | 1962 |
| 178. | Two Friends | Do Sakhiyaan | 1930 | Do Sakhiyaan | **1928** |
| 179. | A Tearful Holi | Aansuwon ki Holi | 1930 | Aansuwon ki Holi | **1928** |
| 180. | The Grinding Woman's Well | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Pisanhari ki Kunwan | **1928** |
| 181. | A Wedding That Turned into a Funeral | Suhaag ka Janaza | 1930 | Suhaag ka Shav | **1928** |
| 182. | The Policeman | Ek Daroga ki Sarguzasht | 1930 | Darogaji | **1928** |
| 183. | Moteramji, the Editor | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Sampadak Moteramji Shastri | **1928** |
| 184. | Selfhood | Khudi | **1928** | ? | 1962 |
| 185. | The Day's First Sale | ? | 1928 | Bohni | **1928** |
| 186. | Desire | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Abhilasha | **1928** |
| 187. | The Rebel | Khaana Barbaad | 1930 | Vidrohi | **1928** |
| 188. | Experience | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Anubhav | **1928** |
| 189. | The Balance Sheet | Husn o Shabaab Kashmakash | 1930 ? | Aaga-Peecha | **1928** |
| 190. | Resignation | Isteefa | 1930 | Isteefa | **1928** |
| 191. | Atonement | Kaffara | 1930 | Praayashchit | **1929** |
| 192. | Nitpicker | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Khuchad | **1929** |
| 193. | The Holi of Love | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Prem ki Holi | **1929** |
| 194. | In Memoriam | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Fatiha | **1929** |
| 195. | A Trip to the Hills | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Parvat Yatra | **1929** |
| 196. | Mother | ? | 1938 | Ma | **1929** |
| 197. | Mourning | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Ghami | **1929** |
| 198. | The Legal Eagle | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Qanooni Kumar | **1929** |
| 199. | Holy War | Jihad | 1930 | Jihad | **1929** |
| 200. | Family Break-up | Alhaidgi | 1930 | Algojya | **1929** |
| 201. | The Live-in Son-in-law | Khaana Damad | 1936 | Ghar Jamai | **1929** |
| 202. | The Woman Who Sold Grass | Ghaaswali | 1930 | Ghaaswali | **1929** |
| 203. | A Narrow Escape | Harz-e Jaan | 1930 | Kavach | **1929** |
| 204. | Two Graves | Mazaar-e Ulfat | 1930 | Do Qabrein | **1930** |
| 205. | Prison | Aashian Barbaad | **1930** | Jeil | 1931 |
| 206. | The Servant of the Nation | Qaum ka Khadim | **1930** | Rashtra ka Sevak | 1962 |
| 207. | The Goddess | Devi | **1930** | Devi | 1962 |
| 208. | Shame | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Dhikkar | **1930** |
| 209. | The Procession | ? | 1930 | Juloos | **1930** |
| 210. | Subhagi | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Subhagi | **1930** |
| 211. | Role Reversal | Biwi se Shauhar | 1930 | Patni se Pati | **1930** |
| 212. | The Closed Door | Band Darwaza | 1930<sup>[3]</sup> | ? | 1962 |
| 213. | Salvation | Nijaat | 1934 | Sadgati | **1931** |
| 214. | Trident | Tirsool | 1930<sup>[3]</sup> | Tirsool | 1962 |
| 215. | The Journey of War | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Samar Yaatra | **1930** |
| 216. | The Wine Shop | *Transliterated* | 1931 | Sharab ki Dukaan | **1930** |
| 217. | A Night in the Month of Poos | Poos ki Raat | 1930 | Poos ki Raat | **1930** |
| 218. | Maiku and the Congress Volunteer | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Maiku | **1930** |
| 219. | The Dream | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Swapan | **1930** |
| 220. | Sacrifice | Jeil | 1931 | Ahuti | **1930** |
| 221. | The Lunatic Lover | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Unmaad | **1931** |
| 222. | Dhaporsankh | ? | 1931 | Dhaporsankh | **1930** |
| 223. | The Final Excuse | Aakhiri Heela | **1930** | Aakhiri Heela | 1931 |
| 224. | The Accusation | ? | 1932 | Laanchan | **1931** |
| 225. | The Performance | ? | 1932 | Dimanstrashun | **1931** |
| 226. | The Debt Collector | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Tagada | **1931** |
| 227. | The Game | Khel | **1931** | Khel (*transliterated*) | 1988 |
| 228. | The Holi Gift | Holi ka Uphaar (*transliterated*) | 2003 | Holi ka Uphaar | **1931** |
| 229. | Inspiration | Tahreek | **?**<sup>[4]</sup> | Prerna | 1931 |
| 230. | Love's Awakening | Tulu-e Muhabbat | 1931 | Prem ka Uday | **1931** |
| 231. | The Last Gift | Aakhiri Tohfa | **1931** | ? | 1962 |
| 232. | The Penalty | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Tawaan | **1931** |
| 233. | The Second Marriage | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Doosri Shaadi | **1931** |
| 234. | The Mistress of the House | Swamini | 1935 | Swamini | **1931** |
| 235. | The Story of Two Bullocks | Do Bail | 1934 | Do Bailon ki Katha | **1931** |
| 236. | The Writer | Praveen Adeeb ki Izzat | 1934 2003 | Lekhak | **1931** |
| 237. | The Co-wife | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Saut | **1931** |
| 238. | The Funeral Feast | Zaad-e Raah | 1936 | Mritak Bhoj | **1932** |
| 239. | The Story of My Life | ? | 1938 | Jeevan Saar | **1932** |
| 240. | The Miracle | ? | 1932 | Chamatkaar | **1932** |
| 241. | A Wife's Testimony against Her Husband | Shikwa Shikayat | 1935 | Gila | **1932** |
| 242. | The Vestal | Sati | 1932 | Sati | 1932<sup>[3]</sup> |
| 243. | The New Wife | ? | 1935 | Naya Vivah | **1932** |
| 244. | The Ailing Sister | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Bimaar Behen | **1932** |
| 245. | Slander | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Kutsa | **1932** |
| 246. | Thakur's Well | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Thakur ka Kuan | **1932** |
| 247. | The Spectacle | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Jhanki | **1932** |
| 248. | Life Sentence | ? | 1936 | Damul ka Qaidi | **1932** |
| 249. | The Votary of Reminiscence | Wafa ka Devta | **1932** | Smriti ka Pujari | 1935 |
| 250. | Kusum | Kusum | **1932** | Kusum | 1934 |
| 251. | The Widow with Sons | Badnaseeb Ma | 1936 | Betonwali Vidhva | **1932** |
| 252. | The Coward | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Kayar | **1933** |
| 253. | The Man Who Defied Fate | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Rangeeley Babu | **1933** |
| 254. | Neur | ? | 1936 | Neur | **1933** |
| 255. | Gilli-Danda | ? | 1935 | Gulli-Danda | **1933** |
| 256. | The Prostitute | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Vaishya | **1933** |
| 257. | The Romantic Editor | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Rasik Sampadak | **1933** |
| 258. | The Boy | Masoom Bachcha | 1935 | Baalak | **1933** |
| 259. | Renunciation | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Vairagya | **1933** |
| 260. | The Flame of Love | Akseer | **1933** | Jyoti | 1933 |
| 261. | The Prisoner | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Qaidi | **1933** |
| 262. | Idgah | Idgah | **1933**<sup>[5]</sup> | Idgah | 1933 |
| 263. | The Queen of Hearts | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Dil ki Rani | **1933**<sup>[5]</sup> |
| 264. | The Murderer | Qaatil | **1934** | ? | 1962 |
| 265. | The Wedding | Baraat | 1933<sup>[3]</sup> | Baraat | 1988 |
| 266. | If You Have No Woes, Buy a Goat! | Gham Nadari Buzbakhar | 1935<sup>[3]</sup> | Koi Ghum Na Ho Tho Bakri Kharid Lo | 1962 |
| 267. | The Goddess of Faithfulness | Wafa ki Devi | 1933<sup>[3]</sup> | ? *Transliterated* | 2009 2010 |
| 268. | Peace of Mind | Sakoon-e Qalb | **1934** | Shanti | 1936 |
| 269. | Intoxication | Nasha | **1934** | Nasha | 1934 |
| 270. | A State of Mind | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Manovritti | **1934** |
| 271. | The Secret | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Jadoo | **1934** |
| 272. | The Minister of the State | ? | 1937 | Riyasat ka Diwaan | **1934** |
| 273. | Pandit Moteram's Diary | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Pandit Moteram ki Diary | **1934** |
| 274. | The Price of Milk | Doodh ki Qeemat | 1937 | Doodh ka Daam | **1934** |
| 275. | Undeserved Praise | Muft Karam Dashtan | 1935 | Muft ka Yash | **1934** |
| 276. | God's Share of Stale Rice | Khuda ka Qahar | 1936 | Baasi Bhaat mein Khuda ka Saajha | **1934** |
| 277. | God's Own Police | Insaaf ki Police | 1935 | Khudai Faujdar | **1934** |
| 278. | My Elder Brother | ? | 1936 | Badey Bhai Sahib | **1934** |
| 279. | The Farce | Swang | **1935** | ? | 1962 |
| 280. | Tulia | Wafa ki Devi | 2003 | Devi | **1935** |
| 281. | The Rules of the House | Zaawiya Nigaah | 1937 | Grih Neeti | **1935** |
| 282. | The Curse of Life | La'nat | 1936 | Jeevan ka Shaap | **1935** |
| 283. | Paying the Price | *Transliterated* | 2003 | ? | **1937**<sup>[3]</sup> |
| 284. | Splashed | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Motor ki Cheentein | **1936**<sup>[3]</sup> |
| 285. | The Assassin's Mother | Qatil ki Ma | 1935<sup>[3]</sup> | ? | 1988 |
| 286. | Miss Padma | Miss Padma | 1936 | Miss Padma | 1936<sup>[3]</sup> |
| 287. | Radiance | Roshni | **1932** | ? | 1988 |
| 288. | Reality | Haqeeqat | **1935** | Tathya | 1937 |
| 289. | Intoxicants, All | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Ye Bhi Nasha, Woh Bhi Nasha | **1937**<sup>[3]</sup> |
| 290. | The Hallowed Feet of the Bridegroom | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Paipunji | **1935** |
| 291. | The Lottery | ? | 1936 | Latari | **1935** |
| 292. | Two Sisters | Do Bahnein | **1935** | ? | 1936 |
| 293. | My First Composition | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Meri Pehli Rachna | **1935** |
| 294. | The Shroud | Kafan | **1935** | Kafan | 1937 |
| 295. | The Holi Holiday | Holi ki Chhutti | 1936<sup>[3]</sup> | Holi ki Chhutti | 1962 |
| 296. | The Mystery | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Rahasya | **1936** |
| 297. | Apples from Kashmir | *Transliterated* | 2003 | Kashmiri Seb | **1936** |
| 298. | An Incomplete Story: A Fragment | ? | **2003**<sup>[3]</sup> | *Transliterated* | 2004 |
| 299. | A Cricket Match | ? | **1937** | ? | 1962 |

###### Remarks

- Some stories have been republished under a different title, which is why there are sometimes two entries in the same cell, for e.g., no. 7.
- Some stories have not been published in one or the other language, but a transliteration from one language to the other is available. This is noted as "Transliterated", for e.g., no. 6.
- A blank entry means that that short story has not been published in that language anywhere even in a transliterated form, for e.g., no. 42.
- If a question mark is put in place of the title, it means that nothing is mentioned in the "Notes" regarding the title in that language, for e.g., no. 57. The missing information can be filled out if someone has access to these stories in that language.
- For nos. 103, 105, and 267, it is not clear whether the original is still available. So, just to be sure, I've mentioned the transliteration information as well.

###### Footnotes

<sup>[1]</sup>It is mentioned that no. 93 was first published in Urdu in April 1922, and published in Hindi in June 1921, so there must be a typo here. Perhaps "April 1922" should have been "April 1921"?

<sup>[2]</sup>It is mentioned that no. 94 was first published in Urdu in July 1921, and published in Hindi in April 1921, so there must be a typo here. Perhaps "April 1921" should have been "April 1922"?

<sup>[3]</sup>The details of first publication is unknown.

<sup>[4]</sup>The place of first publication is mentioned as *Khaak-e Parwana* (2nd ed.), but no year is given. The list of "Popular Editions" in Urdu in the last page shows *Khaak-e Parwana*, Lucknow: Nigar Press, 1928. But it is not clear whether this is the first or the second edition.

<sup>[5]</sup>The date is listed as "1993", but this is surely a typo for "1933".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130792/discussion-between-namaskaram-and-rand-althor).